# synchronize blocks of data mobile client

Tags: android, iphone, synchronization, cloud

I want to build new system that synchronize data between an appliance and mobile clients.
but I want to do it smart and synchronize only blocks of data over https.
on the client side(mobile phone) I want to know which inods were changed and to synchronize only those inods to the server side and vice versa.

The main goal here is not do file syncronization but block syncronization

Mobile clients will be iPhone/iPad/android/windows mobile.

ideas on how to accomplish it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been doing some freelance work for a company called iEffects. They use such a technology for their m-commerce apps and also license it to third parties.

The engine can do bidirectional sync to iOS and Android. You can watch the engine in action, search for Distrelec or Elfa in the App Store - the latter one supports english.